# Getting a "Missing Callback" when trying to call functions in pubnub-angular

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I'm trying to get a simple chat application running, using PubNub and pubnub-angular.  when I try to call `Pubnub.subscribe()`, I get a `Missing Callback`error, referring to line 1 in pubnub.min.js.

Things *appear* to be set up okay:

app.js:

```
angular
.module('pnChatApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'pubnub.angular.service'
])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
        })
        .when('/join', {
            templateUrl: 'views/join.html',
            controller: 'JoinCtrl',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/join'
        });
});
```

main.js:

```
   angular.module('pnChatApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'Pubnub', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, Pubnub) {
    ...
    Pubnub.subscribe({
     channel: $scope.controlChannel,
    });
```

and, index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js"></script>
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pubnub-angular/dist/pubnub-angular.min.js"></script>
```

PubNub *is* getting initialized in another controller, and that happens before I get to this point.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a callback when you subscribe:

```
Pubnub.subscribe({
  channel: $scope.controlChannel,
  callback: function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been doing this through a Udemy course that's about a year old, and I couldn't figure out how their code ran, either.  So, I guess that this is something that has changed since then...